# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'angry'

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am new to python and I was trying the SER solution at 'https://github.com/mldmxm/CTL-MTNet'. I downloaded the publicly available 'SAVEE' and 'EMODB' speech emotion datasets from the internet and added them to the 'CAAM_Code' folder as shown in the image. [image]

When I execute the main file it gives the error, '**FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'angry'**'[image: This is the error]. What I understood was that, there is not an 'angry' folder to search in the dataset though it has used 'angry' in the tuple in Utils.py file. Does that mean that I have to modify the file names in the datasets?

Please note that the SAVEE dataset contains angry speech tracks as 'a01, a02,... etc'. and the EMODB uses a different file naming structure.

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the error in the question.

Comment: @NickODell I updated the error trace.